# Are there any enemies other than Caius?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I have purchased the DLC Lightning's Story: Requiem for a Goddess for Final Fantasy 13-2 and so far have reached level 5 by fighting Cauis several times.

While the adjusted combat system is good, I am finding the repetitive nature of fighting the same battle over and over rather tiring. I defeated Cauis after I reached level 3 and to go on levelling up seems rather redundant if there are not any more difficult battles to come.

Is the only goal of this DLC to 5 star the battle with Cauis or will the story progress and unlock more battles after certain conditions are met?

Comment: @ickleislands When re-tagging with DLC name, I think it would be better to prefix it with the game title (or an abbreviation) so there aren't any conflicts in names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I've seen, the DLC ends when you beat Caius with five stars and then the immediate follow-up fight with the Chaos Behemoth.  Finishing that gives you the conclusion to Lightning's story, followed by the credits, followed by an epilogue.

If you're having trouble getting five stars, leveling up makes the fights easier as more abilities unlock (Haste at level 5 is **huge**).  Winning at a lower level just gives you a higher score you can brag about, if that interests you.

Comment: Ah I haven't beaten Cauis with a 5-star rating yet. It does seem a bit light for a DLC but I guess it was very cheap. Thanks for the information. Will have a go at getting the 5-star rating now.